# Closure of intersection with closed set

Tags: general-topology

For $X$ a topological space, let $A$ and $C$ be subsets of $X$ such that $A$ is dense in $X$ and $C$ is closed.

If the intersection $B:=A\cap C$ is non-empty, does the above already imply that

$$\tag{1} \mathrm{cl}(B) = \mathrm{cl}(A)\cap C\,?$$

(Here, $\mathrm{cl}(Z)$ denotes the closure of a subset $Z\subseteq X$ wrt. the topology on $X$.)

Comment: It'd be more conventional to write $A$ rather than $\mathcal A$ as the latter would more commonly describe a collection of subsets, rather than a subset itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{cl}(A)=X$,  you are asking whether $\operatorname{cl}(A\cap C) = C$.

Take $X = \mathbb R$, $A = \mathbb Q$ and $C = \{0,\pi\}$. Then:

- $A$ is dense in $X$
- $C$ is closed in $X$
- $B \equiv A\cap C = \{0\}$ is nonempty

Yet $\operatorname{cl}(B) = \{0\} \neq \{0,\pi\}= X\cap C = \operatorname{cl}(A)\cap C$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Since $A$ is dense, $cl(A)\cap C=X\cap C=C$.

So we want $A$ dense and $C$ closed where $A\cap C$ is nonempty and $cl(A\cap C)\not=C$. Let $A=\mathbb Q\subseteq\mathbb R$ and let $C$ be a sequence of irrationals converging to $0$. Then $cl(A\cap C)=cl(\{0\})=\{0\}\not= C$.